# How can I retrieve a List of entities from a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I'm trying to retrieve a `List<Student>` from my database.

Basically, the schema is:

```
GradeParalelo ---- GradeStudent ---- Student
```

Where the GradeStudent table holds primary keys for GradeParalelo and Student. **NOTE: The GradeStudent table has an extra column to hold an integer. This is not just an association table.**

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
ColegioDBV2Entities db = new ColegioDBV2Entities();
public List<Student> FindAllStudentsFromGradeParalelo(int gradeParaleloId)
{
    return (db.Students
           .Include("GradeStudents")
           .Include("GradeStudents.GradeParalelo")
           .Where<Student>(s => s.StudentId == gradeParaleloId)).ToList();
}
```

But it's retrieving a single student for every gradeParalelo I choose. Understandably, because I'm comparing a StudentId with a GradeParaleloId. **This is not what I want.**

Can anyone suggest a way to retrieve this collection?

Image that I want to retrieve all students that are in the GradeStudent table with GradeParalelo ID 6.

Basically this, in a more elegant form:

```
public List<Student> FindAllStudentsFromGradeParalelo(int gradeParaleloId)
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    using(GradeStudentRepository repo = new GradeStudentRepository())
    {
        var items = repo.FindAllGradeStudents().Where(g => g.GradeParaleloId == gradeParaleloId);

        StudentRepository studentRepo = new StudentRepository();
        foreach (var o in items)
        {
            students.Add(studentRepo.FindStudent(o.StudentId));
        }
    }

    return students;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
return db.GradeParaleloes.Single(g => g.GradeParaleloId == gradeParaleloId)
                         .GradeStudents.Select(s => s.Student).ToList();
```

Comment: I can't seem to invoke the .SelectMany method, any idea why?

Comment: This seems to be completely wrong. Single return an IQueryable and SelectMany only works against an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Slaks: I had to modify your answer a little bit for it to work. Is it kosher here if I just edit your answer or how does it work? I'll accept this answer because it led to the solution, but in the interest of completeness I'd like to post the working code. :)

Comment: Sure.  Just make a suggested edit.  Alternatively, add your own answer but accept mine.

Answer (score 1):

that is a simple query as:

```
return
    db.Students
        .Where( x => x.GradeParalelo.gradeParaleloId == gradeParaleloId )
        .ToList();
```

if you have the FK right, you just need to call the FK and internally it will link all the needed tables.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but there is an extra column in the association table. I think for this to work you would need to have only the primery key, and the two table foreign keys.

Comment: @Sergio: That shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @SLaks: I think it does because as I have it now, I cannot say `x => x.GradeParalelo` but only `x => x.GradeParaleloes`.